# Express given cos and sin functions in the complex form $\Re\left(re^{i\theta}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $ f(x) = \sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}+5x\right) $ and $g(x) = \sqrt{3}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+5x\right)$. Express the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in the complex form $\Re\left(re^{i\theta}\right)$.

I'm familiar with polar form of a complex number and have just started learning about exponential form which is easy to derive once I have polar form. However, I have no clue how to begin with this problem as none of the sample problems I've encountered dealing with exponential/polar form resemble this. Any help/direction is appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123979/discussion-on-question-by-mcmath-express-given-cos-and-sin-functions-in-the-comp).

Answer (score 0):

$$\Re\left(\sqrt3e^{i(\pi/4+5x)}\right) = \sqrt{3}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+5x\right)=g(x)$$

$$\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}+5x\right)=\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{6}-5x\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+5x\right)\implies\\
\Re\left(\sqrt2e^{i(\pi/6+5x)}\right)=\sqrt2\cos\left(\frac\pi6+5x\right)=f(x)
$$

Comment: I see, now if you'd said I should leave out the i in Euler form that would have made more sense to me.

Comment: I'm sorry.  The $i$ is supposed to be there.  I'll edit it.